# The ul class is not inline with the website logo

Tags: html, css

My navigation UL items are not being displayed inline with my website's logo: Is it possible of the logo size? I've tried adding the width property to the #logo but it wont react...

Picture of problem: http://prntscr.com/p5aygy

Logo properties: 496px x 109

**HTML**

```
    <!--Navigation!!!-->
    <nav>
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/White.png"></div>
        <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop"/>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS FILE**

````
nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;

}
#logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0 0 30px;
}
nav:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
nav ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}


@media (max-width:768px) {
    #logo {
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
        padding: 20px 0 10px;
    }
    nav ul li {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .toggle + a, .menu {
        display: none;
}

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is adding padding to the top of your logo for the #logo selector. That is probably where the spacing is coming from. If you'd like to get rid of the extra spacing on your logo, change the lines for the #logo selector like this:

```
#logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

And again for the media query line below:

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
    #logo {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
        padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
}
```

Also, there may be a chance that your logo image has transparent space around the part that you can see? Sometimes if images aren't trimmed correctly, they can cause unintentional spacing errors.

If you can provide a link to the logo image file itself, we can try to rule this potential issue out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin-top: 10px to the UL part